# Saving related models with a newly created parent ID in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am sure there must be a simple way to do this, but I have been combing the manual and can't find it.

A user creates a new "course" model and in the same form adds a dynamic number of "student" models. Each student belongs to one course. So I receive the data to the controller roughly like this:

```
Array
(
  [Course] => Array(name, etc. etc.),

  [Student] => Array(
    [0] => Array(student details, etc.),
    [1] => Array(student 2 details, etc.))
)
```

Once the controller receives this, I save the Course data to create the new course. I now have the course unique ID from the database...how do I easily save the student data, adding the course_id automatically to each Student, without having to loop through all of them and adding the course_id manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your model relationships are setup correctly, you can use `saveAll()`.

Check the book on [Saving your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data).

Comment: yes, provided you have the correct relationship defined in the models.